# A tag [async] é sinônima de [assincronismo]?

Tags: debate, tags-sinônimas

A tag [async](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/async) deveria ser um sinônimo para [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincronismo)? Na minha opinião, sim.

Hoje, os sinônimos de [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincronismo) são [assíncrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ass%c3%adncrono), [assincrono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincrono) e [asynchronous](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asynchronous).

Comment: As guias de utilização das tags são bem semelhantes, então eu voto sim aqui no Meta (creio que não possa sugerir sinonímia)

Comment: Eu acho que um é sobre o conceito geral, o outro é sobre o mecanismo específico da palavra chave. Pode gerar confusão no uso, mas me parecem diferentes. Só a minha opinião.

Comment: @Maniero lá no SOen eles tem a tag [tag:async-await] que denota o mecanismo, mas acho que fica muito fechado ao .NET.

Comment: Não necessariamente, pode ser uma boa renomear ela assim. Se ninguém tiver objeção aqui eu posso fazer.

Comment: Eu concordo. [tag:async] para [tag:async-await] e [tag:assincronismo] fica como está. Disse que acho que fica um pouco fechado ao .NET pq a maioria das questões do SOen que tem a tag [tag:async-await] tem também a [tag:c#] ou [tag:.net].

Comment: Acho que vai dar problema, pode ter gente usando async para outras coisas, seria melhor editar as perguntas primeiro manualmente e então depois mudaria async para async-await @vnbrs

Comment: Importante lembrar que [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) também faz parte do ES6 no javascript.

Comment: Eu concordo com o @Maniero

async-await é realmente um padrão de controle de execução paralela. Muito comum no .net, já tem no javascript como dito por LucasCosta, mas é uma tendência de ter em várias linguagens como no typescript (óbviamente), no python e por aí vai...

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2015/11/03/what-about-asyncawait/
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html